# C3js - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of null

Tags: javascript, c3

The error message is re-created in this demo:

http://plnkr.co/edit/6Tok16U287sKHQpsRAmX?p=preview

```
var chart = c3.generate({
  data: {
      "columns":  [["B1", 1], ["B2", 2]],
      "type": "donut",
      onclick: onClick,
  },
  donut: { "title": "Iris Petal Width" }
});

function onClick(){
  chart.load({
      columns: [['A_B1', 1], ['B_B1', 2]],
      unload: ['B1', 'B2']
  });
}
```

The documentation for the function is here:

http://c3js.org/reference.html#api-load

Do you think I'm using this wrong or that it's a bug in the library?

--Reponse to comment--
Error also occurs in a fiddle when a section of the donut is clicked.
[image]

If you watch the transition animation closely you can see it hesitate when rendering different sections of the donut.  These errors occur after the rendering.

Comment: It works fine for me. I'm not getting any error messages. Here's a fiddle of it: http://jsfiddle.net/jrdsxvys/12/

Comment: I still see the error with your fiddle.  I added a screenshot to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add defer attribute on SCRIPT elements. It instructs the contents of the script tag to not execute until the page has loaded.

So you'll have something like this:

```
<!-- Load d3.js and c3.js -->
<script src="c3-0.6.7/c3.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<script src="myscript.js" defer></script>
```